# How to omit author field of a citation locally in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I need to create a list of citation shorthands, but my document only uses shorthands to works of one single author. The full citation scheme in shorthands is, therefor, redundant: It should omit the author's name.

That is achievable by reseting the author field with an `\AtBeginShorthands`, like:

```
\AtBeginShorthands{\renewbibmacro*{author}{}}
```

But I also need this behavior in other places: There's a section i the document where I'm planning to put a `description list`, introducing and explaining the main bibliography...

I'd like to create a separate bibliography, something like “*Works by Author Name*”, where the author's name would also be redundant... (I think this supposed to be made inside a `\defbibenvironment` but I don't know how)

So, summarizing:

- 1) how to reset `author bibmacro` inside a single environment
- 2) how to reset `author bibmacro` inside a separated bibliography

Comment: i managed to do the first thing --- reset author bibmacro inside an environment --- simply by adding `\renewbibmacro*{author}{}`at the beginning of the environment (Sorry, there were a problem in my test file)... But I still don't know how to use `\defbibenvironment`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prenote: Although you state to have managed resetting the author field inside an environment, I'm afraid that `\renewbibmacro*{author}{}` will cover many, but not all cases. (The standard bibliography drivers use a lot of different bibmacros!)

For a separated bibliography, I suggest to clone the bibenvironment used by your favourite bibliography/citation style and to add `\clearname{author}` (and `\clearname{editor}`) to the fourth mandatory argument of `\defbibenvironment` -- the one that contains *"code to be executed at the beginning of each entry in the bibliography or the list of shorthands"* (manual, section 3.5.7).

In the following example, I have also semi-automatized the creation of the "Works by author name" bibliographies. `biblatex` doesn't (yet?) feature a `\bibbyauthor` command, but you can declare categories for the different authors and use `\bibbycategory`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibnoauthors}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\clearname{author}%
  \clearname{editor}%
  \item}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Author}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Buthor}
\addtocategory{Author}{A01x,A01y}
\addtocategory{Buthor}{B02}
\defbibheading{Author}{\section*{Works by A.~Author}}
\defbibheading{Buthor}{\section*{Works by B.~Buthor}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01x,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha-First},
}
@misc{A01y,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha-Second},
}
@misc{B02,
  editor = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\bibbycategory[env=bibnoauthors]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @lockstep! It works perfectly! I had just been able to do it my own way: by adding the `\renewbibmacro{author}{}` to the "begin code" section of `\defbibenvironment`, and splitting the bibliography by adding keywords to the `.bib` file... But that's not such a good idea, since it requires to change the bibliography database...

Comment: I still faced same problems with your solution, because the style I'm using (`verbose-trad3`) substitutes the missing `author` field by the `editor` one, and if I `\clearname` both of them, I empoverish my reference too much. The editor's name is important to the point of being irremovable, but not to the point of being highlighted... So, in this case, `\renewbibmacro{author}{}` works best for me.