# Grouping/sorting entries of the bibliography - biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to group entries of the bibliography based on my own preference (not by entry type). Right now I'm adding my bibliography file with all the entries at the end of my document like this:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{src/bib/Literaturverzeichnis}

\begin{document}

\printbibheading

\end{document}
```

I am looking for a way to create some subsets of the bibliography entries and list them one after another up, seperated by a blank line and a specific topic for each subset.

My desired bibliography should look like this:

> Literaturverzeichnis
>
> CaptionSubset1
>   book1
>   book2
>
> Caption Subset2
>   book3
>   article1
>
> .
>   .
>   .

Comment: Use biblatex + biber.

Comment: You can use `keywords`, bibliography categories, or more elaborate filters and checks. If you use categories the big plus is that you can use [`\bibbycategory` to loop over all categories automatically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19899/35864).

Comment: Using categories has the advantage (or disadvantage) that the association with a particular category does not have to be decided on in the `.bib` file but dynamically in the document (though I believe it is possible to automate this process based on `keywords` if you like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by adding tags to the bibentries like this:

```
@book{Book1,
author = {John Doe},
title = {Hello World},
year = {2001},
keywords = {Caption1},
}

@book{Book2,
author = {Max Mustermann},
title = {This is only a test},
year = {2015},
keywords = {Caption2},
}
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
\begin{document}

I am citing \cite{Book1} and \cite{Book2} in the text.

\printbibliography[keyword=Caption1, title={First Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[keyword=Caption2, title={Second Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

and have as many mini-bibliographies according to your wishes. You will have to set keywords for every bibentry, though.

It will look like this:

[image: Two bibliographies for different keywords]

I hope I could help!

Edit: as stated in the comments, the correct argument is `keywords` and not keyword. For adding the bibliography you have to specify e.g. `keyword=Caption1`, though.

Comment: I added for each entry in the bib file a keyword but it doesn't work in my document, and added a print instruction for each keyword but there will be no bibliography. No errors too. Did you tried it?

Comment: The correct name for the field in `biblatex` is `keywords` (mote the `s` at the end). You will also need to wrap all fields in curly braces (or quotes if you must) for them to be processed correctly.

Comment: @d4rty See my comment above and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43829/35864)

Comment: I am sorry, I was slacking! Edited

Comment: You are missing a comma after `Book`, the citekey needs to be separated by a `,` from the rest of the entry. I think your answer would benefit from a full example showing the code *in situ*. If you find the time, you can also explain bib categories and highlight the difference.